# Iterating through a pandas dataframe and inserting new values into an empty column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, iteration

I'm relatively new to Pandas and am having trouble iterating through the values in a given column in my dataset and finding those cells which contain a specific string.

```
Address,City
['1234 Apple Drive', 'San Francisco', 'CA'],''
['4678 Bannana Street', 'Austin', 'TX'],''
```

For this example, I want to a) extract just the street information of b) addresses which contain the string 'Street' and c) place them in a newly inserted column named 'Street.'

```
Address,City,Street
['1234 Apple Drive', 'San Francisco', 'CA'],'',''
['4678 Bannana Street', 'Austin', 'TX'],'','4678 Bannana Street'
```

I know how to insert a new column into my dataset. My code so far looks like this (assume my current dataset has only two columns and the entries from the example):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame, read_csv

df = pd.read_csv('dataset.csv', sep = '\t')
df.insert(loc=3, column = 'street', value=str)
```

The rest of what I have isn't pretty and has been useless so far. Any help with executing a, b and c is much appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
import re

df = pd.DataFrame([['1234 Apple Drive', 'San Francisco', 'CA'],
                   ['4678 Bannana Street', 'Austin', 'TX']],
                  columns=['Address', 'City', 'State'])

df['Street'] = df.Address.str.extract(r'([\S]+)\s+Street', flags=re.IGNORECASE)
print df

               Address           City State   Street
0     1234 Apple Drive  San Francisco    CA      NaN
1  4678 Bannana Street         Austin    TX  Bannana
```

If you wanted to include street number as well:

```
import re

df[['Street Number', 'Street']] = df.Address.str.extract(r'(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+Street', expand=True, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
print df

               Address           City State Street Number   Street
0     1234 Apple Drive  San Francisco    CA           NaN      NaN
1  4678 Bannana Street         Austin    TX          4678  Bannana

​
```

---

#### Note

using pandas 0.18.1 I get a future warning if I don't specify the `expand` flag.  Use this instead.

```
df['Street'] = df.Address.str.extract(r'([\S]+)\s+Street', expand=False, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
```

Comment: Trying this with my current csv file, I'm getting an error in the extract call: "extract() got an unexpected keyword argument 'expand'". Any ideas?

Comment: version.  I'm using pandas 0.18.1.  I get a future warning if I don't use it.  Try to take it out for now.  What's more is that I'm only extracting one value so it doesn't really matter.  I'll update post.

Comment: I upgraded and could use extract just fine. Just got this to work for my local file. Thank you so much!

Comment: If I wanted to extract additional information from the Address column and put it in a different, new column (Street Number, 1234), how could I go about doing that?

Comment: Updated post to accommodate street number.

Answer (score 1):

```
df['street'] = df['Address'].str.replace('\[|\]','').str.split(',', expand=True)[0]
df['street_filtered'] = df.ix[df.street.str.contains('Street'),'street']
```